# Why does Swift invoke the wrong initialiser?

Tags: swift, uinavigationcontroller, overriding, designated-initializer

I have a UINavigationController subclass:

```
fileprivate class NavController: UINavigationController {

  override init(navigationBarClass: AnyClass?, toolbarClass: AnyClass?) {
    super.init(navigationBarClass: navigationBarClass, toolbarClass: toolbarClass)
    ...
  }

  required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
  }

  ...
}
```

I instantiate this class as:

```
navController = NavController(navigationBarClass: nil, toolbarClass: nil)
```

This compiles, but fails at runtime:

```
AppDelegate.swift: 87: 19: fatal error: use of unimplemented initializer 'init(nibName:bundle:)' for class 'NavController'
```

I don't understand why **init(nibName:bundle:)** is being called, when I specified the keywords **navigationBarClass:** and **toolbarClass:**.

If I delete all the initialisers from my subclass, it works fine, which is confusing since overriding a method / initialiser that only calls super should be a noop.

Line 87 is the one where the class is declared. I tried stepping in with a debugger, but I can't step into UIKit code, only my code.

In case this matters, this is on iOS 10 and Swift 3.

Answer (score 1):

The issue stems from the life cycle of the `UINavigationController`, because if you print the functions when overriding all the `init`s the console looks like this:

```
init(nibName:bundle:)
init(navigationBarClass:toolbarClass:)
```

So you also have to override the `init(nibName:bundle:)` as it is called first, like this:

```
class NavController: UINavigationController {

    /* Properties */

    override init(nibName nibNameOrNil: String?, bundle nibBundleOrNil: Bundle?) {
        super.init(nibName: nibNameOrNil, bundle: nibBundleOrNil)
    }

    override init(navigationBarClass: AnyClass?, toolbarClass: AnyClass?) {
        super.init(navigationBarClass: navigationBarClass, toolbarClass: toolbarClass)
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

}

extension NavController {
    /* Methods */
}
```

Comment: Im not sure, placing that code in a current project works fine with no issues, being implemented `let navController = NavController(navigationBarClass: nil, toolbarClass: nil)`

Comment: This works, though it's a mystery why — overriding something to just call super should be a noop.

Comment: Its just swift being swift, loves to annoy us all

Comment: Not sure if I can ask a continuous question here. Once after initializing the custom nav bar. How to access that navigation bar that gives my custom type? I apologize if it is a new question.